# Inherited Cisco Catalyst 6509 Supervisor 2 engine

Tags: cisco-catalyst, cisco-6500

I inherited a Cisco Catalyst with the below modules.  I am trying to find out if I have the latest firmware for the various modules.  Cisco's site is not being help full as the sup2 is eol.  If any one knows of a site that lists that info or knows off the top of their head I would appriciate it. the rp is close enough but the sp doesnt have any image in it and i have no idea if 7.1 is the latest base rommon.

supervisor 2 (Active)    WS-X6K-SUP2-2GE Fw 7.1 Sw 12.2(18)SXF1 / WS-F6K-PFC2  Hw3.2 /WS-F6K-MSFC2 Hw2.5 /

MSFC2 is running c6msfc2-rm2.srec.122-17r.S1 (s5 I believe is latest.)

rtr2#show rom-monitor slot 1 sp

Region F1: INVALID

Region F2: INVALID

Currently running ROMMON from S (Gold) region

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cisco Catalyst 6500 Series Supervisor Engine 2 / MSFC2](http://software.cisco.com/download/type.html?mdfid=280829673&flowid=20128)

Latest CatOS ROMMON: 7.1.1
Latest IOS ROMMON: 12.2.17r(S5)
Latest IOS: 12.2.18-SXF17b

All require a valid smartnet contract to access. (even for EOL crap.)

Comment: Without a Cisco Smartnet contract, the customer will have to buy the 6500 spare CD to allow upgrade to support this.

This will come with the standard cost for software.

e.g. IP Services is $10,000

 

Here is the part number and link:

6500-SW-SPARECD

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps708/prod_bulletin0900aecd806780a3.html

Comment: Thanks for the mention of the smartnet contract that lead me to the above tidbit.